# What is the quickest way to clean up all warnings in all XIB / Storyboard files In Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, warnings, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

In Xcode, whenever I see warnings (usually about misplaced elements) appear in the XIB / Storyboard, I have to:

1. Select the container (Usually the containing view controller or the top most view)
2. From the Xcode menu select `Editor` -> `Resolve Auto Layout Issues` -> `All views in <container name>` -> Appropriate action ( For instance: `Update frames`) to resolve the issues.

The above method takes requires steps and a bit time consuming to me. It would be great if I could:
- Resolve all warnings for ALL view controllers in a storyboard/XIB file
- Even better resolve ALL warnings of all storyboard/XIB files available in the project

If you have any idea please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many ways, I think for now this is the quickiest method I know:

1. Open the Xcode issue navigator (see the image below)
2. Type `frame for` in the text box at the bottom to filter layout issues.
3. Click on the warning one by one and press `Command + Option + =`.

That's it!

Personally I also found out that doing this way can significantly shorten the time to click through all warnings:

1. Use the left hand's index finger to press left `Command` key
2. Use the left hand's middle finger to press left `option` (or `alt`) key
3. Using right hand's pinky to press `=` key
4. Use right hand's thumb to click on the touch pad, BUT don't move it on the touch pad so that I can always click on the FIRST warning

[image: Xcode issue navigator]