# How to more easily "update all frames" in autolayout in Xcode7?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, xcode7

The "Update Frames" calls are often grayed-out in Xcode

[image]

the only way I know to have it update frames to match your constraints, is, tediously select your highest-level view and than (sometimes) you can fish in the menu bar for "Selected Views"->"Update Frames". Further, "All Views"->"Update Frames" would appear to often simply not work or work in a way I can't understand.

Surely there's just **a keystroke** or button which updates **all frames** straight away to match any newly-entered constraints (such as those made using control-drag).

---

Note .. for 2016 you can use this very handy button, which at least brings up the same sub-menu as you can find by searching in the menu bar menu.

[image]

However it would seem (see my comments w/ ZaBlanc below) that there is perhaps actually an Xcode bug, and you CAN NOT assign a keystroke to the "All Views" items. (The ones you usually use.)

## Even worse .. in Xcode 8 ...

they seem to have ***removed the 'update frames' option*** ... WTH

Comment: That calls for a custom plugin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no keystroke for update all frames, but here's a key tip:

- If you have a misplaced views, press the yellow arrow in the document outline (the views tree to the left of canvas), press yellow triangle on any view in the list, then select update frames and check `Apply to all views in container` - this will update all misplaced views in the selected view controller

[image]

Additionally, you probably already know:

- You can add a new constraint with `Add New Constraints` button in canvas bottom right and select "Update frames" option.
- You can select any view by mouse-click and holding <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> keys - this will show you the list of all the views, that intersects with mouse pointer. After that you can select update frames menu item on a selected misplaced view.

Comment: to update a single view you can hit <cmd> <shift> <=> to update that one object, but to do a group of objects you will have to click on the super view and then resolve auto layout issues by updating the frame which can be done in the editor tab or hitting the 4th option on the bottom bar under the storyboard.

Answer (score 23):

It's easy. Go to Preferences -> Key Bindings. Type "Update Frames" on the top. You'll see two appear. You'll want the bottom one (it will be the one without a keyboard shortcut assigned.)

Assign it to ⌘= or anything else you like.

Life changed.

[image]
[image]

- Just for anyone reading, with **Xcode 8.3**. The popup menu command no longer exists. The **menu bar** command Editor -> Update Frames does work.  However there's a bug, the default key binding on that does not work. If you add a custom key combo, that custom key combo does work.

Comment: Yes, the tip above will do it.

Comment: I added another screenshot. Hope it helps!

Comment: This has **changed my life**. I'm clicking over a bounty, thanks!

Comment: As a curiosity @zablanc - now in Xcode 8.3, for some reason the default keystroke simply doesn't work.  (Using that menu bar option itself (Editor -> Update Frames) works fine.)  If however I just change the key binding to another one (I use ctl-opt-cmd-F), it does work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The same as you, I thought that it's very annoying to fix the misplaced views manually by selecting them and choose that boring option from Xcode menu. After trying hard to shorten the time to fix the layout issues, I had to admit that there is no way to call the function "Update Frames" from command line. So I ended up doing this way:

1. Open Xcode warnings & error inspector window
2. Filter all layout warnings by using the keyword "frame for"
3. Click on warnings to quickly locate to the misplaced views then press `Command + Option + =`

That's the fastest way I know. Please try it out!

[image]

You could also find more details [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630880/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-clean-up-all-warnings-in-all-xib-storyboard-files)

Comment: No, it's still there. The above screenshot was taken with Xcode 7! :)

Comment: hi Ducky - the `Command Shift Equals` is not working for me: exactly what should I click, and then use that keystroke? Thank YOU

Comment: Hmm, I'm really sorry ... CommandOptionEqual just doesn't do anything for me ... maybe the version has changed or something??  Nevertheless, an upvote!

Comment: The shortcut key must be written right on Xcode menu. After selecting a misplaced view controller, You can easily find it at:  Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> All views in <container name> -> Appropriate action ( For instance: Update frames)

Comment: you know, it's utterly weird .. but that does not work for me .. I see what you mean now on the menu ... the key combo just doesn't work!   :-O   maybe I haven't "selected frame" right...  I don't know!  thanks for bringing this to my attention...

Comment: The point is to select a misplaced view / view controller before pressing the shortcut, AND there must be no conflict with orther shortcuts in your system. Check OS preferences or Xcode preference to update the shortcut as you wish if necessary